# Same file on same server. Different loading speed for each domain. Why?

Tags: javascript, performance, file, server

I have a weird issue. There are multiple websites using the same template. So in every domain directory the same file is located and all are on the same server. But on one website the response time for this one .js file is way off and it sometime takes a few seconds more than on any of the other sites.

If I include the file from other domains, by linking to it, everything is fine. But as soon as it's taken from it's original directory it gets very slow. I compared them and copied it over, they are totally identical.

I also moved the project to another server but it's still the same issue. It's like the path to this file is doomed or something.

Comment: Sounds like a DNS problem. Check your TTL values with a tool like `dig`. Long, slow DNS queries can explain this performance discrepancy. To isolate DNS either add the domains to your "hosts" file, or use `curl` to the IP with a manually set `Host:` header.

Comment: please provide some example of what you are seeing. more details about how did you configure your stack may help.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem with my server, I'm almost sure it was caused by the **DNS server**. Seem like some servers are faster than others.

In my case, to reduce the delay, I'm using **`nginx` server-side cache**.

If you want to deliver your content even faster, you should have a look in [CDN services](https://www.globaldots.com/content-delivery-network-explained/) (Cloudflare, Cloudera, and others) to serve your content with low latency in whatever region you need.